# How do I run Django seed data in my MySql docker image?

Tags: mysql, django, docker, docker-compose, seeding

I'm using Python 3.7, Django 2 and attempting to build a docker container housing both MySql and Django app images.  I have this docker-compose.yml file ...

```
version: '3'

services:
  web:
    restart: always
    build: ./web
    ports:           # to access the container from outside
      - "8000:8000"
    environment:
      DEBUG: 'true'
    command: /usr/local/bin/gunicorn maps.wsgi:application -w 2 -b :8000

  mysql:
    restart: always
    image: mysql:5.7
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: 'maps_data'
      # So you don't have to use root, but you can if you like
      MYSQL_USER: 'chicommons'
      # You can use whatever password you like
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'password'
      # Password for root access
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'password'
    ports:
      - "3406:3406"
    volumes:
      - my-db:/var/lib/mysql

volumes:
  my-db:
```

Here is my web/Dockerfile ...

```
FROM python:3.7-slim

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install

RUN apt-get install -y libmariadb-dev-compat libmariadb-dev
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends gcc \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN python -m pip install --upgrade pip
RUN mkdir -p /app/

WORKDIR /app/

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN python -m pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . /app/
```

If I want to seed my MySql image with Python data, how would I achieve that?  Without docker, I would normally run this

```
python manage.py loaddata maps/fixtures/country_data.yaml
```

in a virtual environment.  Not quite sure where this command would go, or even what it shoudl be, to do this in my docker image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This command should probably run only once and not every time that you want to bring up your stack (`docker-compose up`). If you do this, it might cause `IntegrityError`s and that is not what you want.

If this is the case, you should probably run that command manually. After the containers are up and running, you can run the command like this:

```
docker exec {web_container_name} python manage.py loaddata maps/fixtures/country_data.yaml
```

It is best to not include this command in your `Dockerfile` body or an `entrypoint` per se.

**Notice**

Be sure to replace `{web_container_name}` with the correct name, which you will be able to find by issuing `docker ps` command.

**But**

If you really want to do that, I recommend you consider using `ENTRYPOINT` directive in your `Dockerfile`. For doing that, create a new file called `entrypoint.sh` and change the `Dockerfile` like below:

**entrypoint.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

python manage.py loaddata maps/fixtures/country_data.yaml

exec "$@"
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM python:3.7-slim

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install

RUN apt-get install -y libmariadb-dev-compat libmariadb-dev
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends gcc \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN python -m pip install --upgrade pip
RUN mkdir -p /app/

WORKDIR /app/

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN python -m pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY entrypoint.sh /app/
COPY . /app/
RUN chmod +x entrypoint.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["/app/entrypoint.sh"]
```

Comment: Running the seed command more than once won't cause an IntegrityConstraint error, luckily.  However, isn't there a way to include this command when the container is first built and then only have it run if I'm rebuilding the container?  As you can see, I would prefer not to run it as a standalone command.

Comment: Hey @Dave, was this answer helpful for you? If so, please mark this post as answered. And if it didn't solve your problem, please elaborate so we can solve it.

Comment: Hi @nima, was out of town for a bit just getting back to this.  Unfortunately, running "docker-compose up" results in the error, 'ERROR: for maps_web_1  Cannot start service web: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:346: starting container process caused "exec: \"/app/entrypoint.sh\": permission denied": unknown'

Comment: Ah, actually a small tweak was needed -- moving "COPY . /app/" above the "chmod" command, and now everything is running perfectly.  Thx!

Comment: Oh sorry, I will edit the answer too. You're welcome btw.